# Binding with Many to Many relationship in UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, data-binding, uwp

**Problem**: I have a database with 3 tables: Teacher; Class; and Teacher_Class;
Teacher can teaches many classes and class can have many teachers. I can bind and show teacher list or class list fine, but i don't know how to add another list inside list of teacher, showing which class they're teaching. Found some solutions for .Net c# but none for UWP. Here're my code:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="300*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Teacher list" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:TeacherWithClasses">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind teacher.TeacherID}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind teacher.TeacherName}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Teaching class(es):"></TextBlock>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind listOfClasses}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Class">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ClassName}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "SchoolDatabase.sqlite");
        SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);          
        conn.CreateTable<Teacher>();
        conn.CreateTable<Class>();

        List<TeacherWithClasses> temp = conn.Query<TeacherWithClasses>(@"select t.TeacherID, t.TeacherName, c.ClassID, c.ClassName from Class c join Teacher_Class tc on c.ClassID = tc.ClassID join Teacher t on tc.TeacherID = t.TeacherID");
        ObservableCollection<TeacherWithClasses> listOfTeachers = new ObservableCollection<TeacherWithClasses>(temp);
        listView.ItemsSource = listOfTeachers;
    }
```

Class:

```
class Teacher
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    public Teacher() { }
}

class Class
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ClassID { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public Class() { }
}

class TeacherWithClasses
{
    public Teacher teacher;
    public List<Class> listOfClasses;

    public TeacherWithClasses(Teacher _teacher, List<Class> _listOfClasses)
    {
        teacher = _teacher;
        listOfClasses = _listOfClasses;
    }

    //public TeacherWithClasses() { }
}
```

SQLite:

```
insert into Teacher (TeacherName) values ('Lee Jun Hoo');
insert into Teacher (TeacherName) values ('Marthew Andy');

insert into Class (ClassName) values ('1A');
insert into Class (ClassName) values ('1B');
insert into Class (ClassName) values ('1C');

create table Teacher_Class
(
TeacherID int not null,
ClassID int not null,
foreign key(TeacherID) references Teacher(TeacherID),
foreign key(ClassID) references Class(ClassID)
);

insert into Teacher_Class values (1,1);
insert into Teacher_Class values (1,2);
insert into Teacher_Class values (2,2);
insert into Teacher_Class values (2,3);
```

The app right now:

[image]

What i need:

[image]

**Update new problem:** i tried to use Backstar suggest and a stuck at where he left, i tried to fill the list with these code:

```
        List<TeacherWithClasses> temp = conn.Query<TeacherWithClasses>(@"select t.TeacherID, t.TeacherName, c.ClassID, c.ClassName from Class c join Teacher_Class tc on c.ClassID = tc.ClassID join Teacher t on tc.TeacherID = t.TeacherID");
        ObservableCollection<TeacherWithClasses> listOfTeachers = new ObservableCollection<TeacherWithClasses>(temp);
        listView.ItemsSource = listOfTeachers;
```

Exception at first query, list temp : Constructor on type 'App3.TeacherWithClasses' not found. So i added an empty constructor, no exception, the app run, but not display binding text.

I am grateful if u could show me answer in code or just a link to example, tutorial for this problem is fine too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the itemsource is bind in code behind. The selected property u suggest help me get id of a teacher if i select a row from the listview. Then from that teacher id i can get classes teached by that teacher right? What i stuck at is without select any teacher, the list still display list of teacher + classes teach by them.

Comment: Each row will show 1 teacher info include ID and Name. With SelectedItem  Change event i can do i show a pop up mess or show thing with list of classes teached by that teacher, this i what u meant in first comment right? This only happen if i select a teacher. What i want is the app auto get ID of each Row and show list of class based on that row Teacher's ID.

Comment: @Henk: thanks for the clue.

Comment: Still stuck after 3 hours of researching more, most of MVVM tutorial i found is in wpf and none of them access a problem similiar to this. I could really use some help in finding solution for this with or without MVVM right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can work if you create a custom class which joins all the data you want show in a child list of a list.

1. Create a new class all of the properties you want show in the list
   and its child list. In this class declare a new list which will hold
   items of classes related to teacher.
2. Create a new list containing this new class.
3. Fill the list.
4. Add it to the list as ItemSource. Bind to the child list. Use Path
   property where is necessary.

Example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="300*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Teacher list" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" ItemSource="{x:Bind listOfTeachers"}>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="TeacherWithClasses">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=teacher.TeacherID}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=teacher.TeacherName}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Teaching class(es):"></TextBlock>
                    <ListView ItemSource="{x:Bind listOfClasses}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>                     
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="Class">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ClassName}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>                    
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>

class TeacherWithClasses
{
    public Teacher teacher;    
    List<Class> listOfClasses;

    public TeacherWithClasses(Teacher _teacher, List<Class> _listOfClasses)
    {
        teacher = _teacher;
        listOfClasses = _listOfClasses;
    }
}

class Class
{
    public int ClassID { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public Class() { }
}
```

Then you have to create the listOfTeachers List:

```
ObservableCollection<TeacherWithClasses> listOfTeachers = fill the list with items
```

Comment: Have some problems with your code, mostly in xaml required using datatype for x:bind field, fixed (not sure if i fixed it right) like the code i updated in the question. And stuck at where you left at for 3 hour. Please guide me more.

Comment: Sorry I was at work and some details fell out of my scope at the moment. I edited the code with DataType.